# QTimer.singleShot expected 'QTimer', got an 'int'

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4

I'm trying to learn PyQt using Mark Summerfield's Rapid GUI Programing with Python and Qt.  However, I am stuck on the first example.  (I am using Python 2.7)

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

try:
    due = QTime.currentTime()
    message = "Alert!"
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        raise ValueError
    hours, mins = sys.argv[1].split(":")
    due = QTime(int(hours), int(mins))
    if not due.isValid():
        raise ValueError
    if len(sys.argv) > 2:
        message = " ".join(sys.argv[2:])
except ValueError:
        message = "Usage: alert.pyw HH:MM [optional message]"

while QTime.currentTime() < due:
    time.sleep(20)  # 20 seconds

label = QLabel("<font color=red size=72><b>" + message + "</b></font>")
label.setWindowFlags(Qt.SplashScreen)
label.show()
QTimer.singleShot(60000, app.quit)  # 1 minute
app.exec_()
```

The second to last line, i.e. `QTimer.singleShot(60000, app.quit)` gives an error that it Expected type 'QTimer', got 'int' instead.  When I look up the method definition it looks like the first argument should be an int.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this when running your example with python-2.7.9 and pyqt-4.11.3 in a console. What version of PyQt are you using, and how are you running the code? `QTimer.singleShot` is a static function, so it shouldn't require an an instance to be passed as the first argument.

Comment: This is what I had/have; I rebuilt the Conda environment and things seemed to start working.  Thank you so much for taking the time to test the code!
('Python version:', '2.7.9 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Dec 18 2014, 16:57:52) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]')
('Qt version:', '4.8.6')  
('SIP version:', '4.15.5')
('PyQt version:', '4.10.4')

Answer (score 0):

You could create an instance:

```
QTimer().singleShot(60000, app.quit)
```

But `QTimer.singleShot(60000, app.quit)` just gives a warning in the editor, it does not actually cause an error.

Comment: I rebuilt the Conda environment and everything started working.  I still get the error in the IDE but not when I run it.  Thank You!

Comment: No worries,  singleShot is a static method so there should be no reason why it could not be called using `QTimer.singleShot`